# Angular 6 rendering HTML tag with ngFor loop with interpolation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, ngfor

i'm having a problem with template rendering (ANGULAR 6) and a library for creating floating panels ([jsPanel 6](https://jspanel.de/index.html)) that is plain javascript. To sum up:

In my template, after rendering it, i have one BUTTON that triggers this function:

```
public openPanel()
  {

    let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];

    let tag : string = '<ul> <li *ngFor="let i of list"> {{ i }} </ul>';

      jsPanel.create({
        theme:       'primary',
        contentSize: {
            width: function() { return Math.min(730, window.innerWidth*0.9);},
            height: function() { return Math.min(400, window.innerHeight*0.5);}
        },
        position:    'center-top 0 250',
        animateIn:   'jsPanelFadeIn',
        headerTitle: 'I\'m a jsPanel',
        content:     tag,
        onwindowresize: true
    });

  }
```

The problem is that Angular doesn't render the ngFor, it doesn't go trough the loop and also, it doesnt get the ``{{ i }}´´ interpolation. I'm using typescript by the way.

[result after clicking the button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGYyo.png)

Is there away without using Dynamic Component Loader to render that?.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it does not working. Why don't you construct HTML with javascript as follows ?

```
public openPanel()
  {

    let list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];

    let tag: string = list.map(i => 
      `<ul><li>${i}</ul>`
    ).join('');

      jsPanel.create({
        theme:       'primary',
        contentSize: {
            width: function() { return Math.min(730, window.innerWidth*0.9);},
            height: function() { return Math.min(400, window.innerHeight*0.5);}
        },
        position:    'center-top 0 250',
        animateIn:   'jsPanelFadeIn',
        headerTitle: 'I\'m a jsPanel',
        content:     tag,
        onwindowresize: true
    });

  }
```